# Trigger different JavaScript functions on different selections in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript

I have simple dropdown menu

```
<select name="dog-names" id="dog-names">
  <option value="rigatoni">Rigatoni</option>
  <option value="dave">Dave</option>
</select>
```

I want to trigger different JavaScript functions when each one of them are selected 
 for example I want to alert "Hello world" whenever Rigatoni is selected and I want to alert "I love you" whenever Dave is selected

```
function Hello() { 
alert("Hello world");
}

function Love() {
alert("I love you");
}
```

I know I could just pass the value to a function as a parameter and then use if/else but I have to avoid including conditional statements in my code. 
 is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// declare function dictionary
const fns = {
  rigatoni: Hello,
  dave: Love
}

function Hello() {
  alert("Hello world");
}

function Love() {
  alert("I love you");
}
// add event listener
const names = document.querySelector('#dog-names').addEventListener('change', ({target}) => {
  // run function based on value
  fns[target.value]()
})
```

```html
<select name="dog-names" id="dog-names">
  <option value="rigatoni">Rigatoni</option>
  <option value="dave">Dave</option>
</select>
```

Comment: been struggling on this one for a while, this helped! thanks